# Tomcat project cleaning error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I try to clean the project from tomcat. I'm getting this error:

> Could not delete <file name>. May be locked by another process.

Is there any way to counter this problem?

Comment: Did you shut down tomcat before trying to do that?

Comment: How did you get past this?  I have the same issue!

Comment: I had a similar issue [here][1]. Might be of some help for others.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615284/eclipse-wtp-m2eclipse-can-neither-clean-nor-publish-to-tomcat/9620705#9620705

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, try to just **restart** tomcat.

Then, try to **clean** everything:

- Clean the Tomcat server: in Eclipse, right click on `Tomcat vX.Y Server > Clean`.
- Clean the project: menu `Project > Clean`.
- Clean the resource of the server: click the ‣ next to `Tomcat vX.Y Server`, underneath it your project is displayed, right click it and select "Clean Module Work Directory..."

You can also try to start the server **in Debug mode**: right click `Tomcat vX.Y Server > Debug`.

Answer (score 1):

You just try to clean your tomcat server .

- Go to tomcat server properties >switch to location >apply
- Then clean your tomcat directory .
- Clean Tomcat

Its work for me

Answer (score -1):

The message is good, you have another process/application currently using the resources eclipse is trying to clean. If you're on linux, you can use lsof to find it. On windows, you have to guess or go through all applications currently opened.